# Priveleges problem using rsync

Tags: permissions, rsync

I am trying to move a web directory from serverA to serverB I have sudo priveleges on both, but I do not know root's password.

Using the command

`rsync -a serverA:/var/www serverB:/var/`

I get an error that I don't have the priveleges to mkdir on serverB. Makes sense the permissions should not let me write to /var without sudo.

So I try the same command with sudo. But it asks for root@serverB password. Which I don't know. I don't think I ever set one.

The same thing happens if I run the command from either server.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a user it will default to the local user's name. If you run with `sudo` it thinks you're root, that's why you get that behavior.

Try being explicit:

```
sudo rsync -a your-user@serverA:/var/www target-user@serverB:/var/
```

Comment: I totally forgot about specifying the user. I use the same username on both so I am not in the habit of specifying it. Thanks